# passing an already created tree root Node to other function. In that function it crashes after one level

Tags: c++, tree

Each node has vector of children
The no. of childnodes comes fine but the childnodes of root seem to be corrupted.Please provide an interface through which I can pass my already populated tree to other function.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It might help if provided some code of what you are doing.  In addition, what have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and (for the impatient) read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: SO is neither a debugging service nor a society of telepaths.